# Trouble accessing Laravel activity log properties in database

Tags: php, laravel, activitylog

I am trying to access the items inside the array in the **'properties'** column when the activity is logged into the database, but I am not sure how to do it.

I have been able to get the log items from the **'properties'** column in the table to my ActivityController but I am not sure what to do from there. I need to split it into the **'attributes'** and **'old'** arrays within the initial array to display to the user what has changed. I also further need to go into the **'attributes'** and **'old'** arrays to get the old and updated values.

I have tried passing it into the view and splitting in there but I have only been able to get the individual 'properties' arrays and display that with no formatting

```
{  
   "attributes":{  
      "first_name":"Kevingh"
   },
   "old":{  
      "first_name":"Kevin"
   }
}
```

// this is what the data looks like

I should have just the **'attributes'** in one array variable and the **'old'** in another to access each.

Comment: `json_decode()`?????

Comment: That gives me an error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"